# Cant send e-mail by php mail on first attempt

Tags: forms, email, php

I'm trying to send an email via SMTP using PHPMailer on my site, it works the second time I try (use submit), but the first time it says it cannot authenticate, login or password is invalid. I have searched a lot and can't find the answer, can someone help me please?
By the way I'm using JSON to get the PHP response in an alert. My host doesn't have "smtp." in front because support told me to do it this way.

This is the code:

```
else {
$phpmail = new PHPMailer();

$phpmail->IsSMTP(); // envia por SMTP
$phpmail->Host = "velvetwebdesign.com.br"; // SMTP servers
$phpmail->Port = "587"; // Port
$phpmail->SMTPAuth = true; // Caso o servidor SMTP precise de autenticação
$phpmail->SMTPDebug  = 1; 
$phpmail->Username = "email@velvetwebdesign.com.br"; // SMTP username
$phpmail->Password = "xxxxxxx"; // SMTP password

$phpmail->IsHTML(true);

$phpmail->From = 'email@velvetwebdesign.com.br';
$phpmail->FromName = $_POST['nome'];

$phpmail->AddAddress("velvetwebdesign@velvetwebdesign.com.br");
$phpmail->AddAddress($_POST['email']);
$phpmail->Subject = 'Contato Velvet Web Design';
$phpmail->Body .= "<b>Cliente:</b> ".$_POST['nome']."<br />";
$phpmail->Body .= "<b>E-mail:</b> ".$_POST['email']."<br />";
$phpmail->Body .= "<b>Telefone:</b> ".$_POST['telefone']."<br />";
$phpmail->Body .= "<b>Assunto:</b> ".$_POST['assunto']."<br /><br />";
$phpmail->Body .= "<b>Mensagem:</b><br />".nl2br($_POST['mensagem'])."<br /><br />";
$phpmail->Body .= "Recebemos a sua mensagem, responderemos em breve.<br />";
$phpmail->Body .= "http://www.velvetwebdesign.com.br/";

$send = $phpmail->Send();

if($send){
    echo "A Mensagem foi enviada com sucesso. Enviaremos uma copia para o seu e-mail tambem.";
    exit; 
}else{
    echo "Tente novamente por favor. Erro: " .$phpmail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
```

}
 ?>

Comment: Do a little debugging and get the error message produced.

Comment: What error message are you getting..

Comment: Thats the problem, i can`t get it two times, it`s like i cant connect on first, but when connected it works. If u guys can give it a try: http://www.velvetwebdesign.com.br/#contato.html it`s on portuguese but i guess you can understand it (enviar=send)

Comment: I tested it, it worked fine for me... tried it for one time to my gmail and got inmideatly through...

Comment: Try 3094-9384, but it`s from brazil, not Portugal.

Comment: So i guess it`s a server problem, like can`t connect sometimes, is there someway i can instead of echoring the error, try to send it again (it works on second time, i trying to echo something like this when it wont work: ""try again please", but i would like to resend it without letting the user know it wont send on first attemp) Is there a way?